# Approval process - action

Tags: approval-process

Currently Approve/ Reject actions are available in approval process. We have a requirement where user wants another option, like Escalate. Is it possible to add custom actions to approval process? if not is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

How do you want Escalate to be implemented? If you're asking to override the standard Approve/Reject options, as far as I know that's not possible - however, you can create Approval Actions through the basic UI and associate them with steps in the Approval Processe, but it's limited to things like field updates (which could meet your requirement), Task creation, etc. Go to the Approval Process and select Add New action.

See more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_creating_approval_actions.htm&language=en_US).

Approvals are also [exposed via Apex](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_example.htm), so if you wanted Escalate to be implemented in a different way, it would certainly be achievable.

Comment: Thanks Brian..    Escalate should directly assign it to another user.  Add New action, adds action within approve/reject  process. My requirement is to add one more option along with approve/reject.

Answer (score 0):

Out of box it is currently not possible and here is the link to the [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l9l4AAA).Please vote for it.

Comment: Its a must option!!  Anyways now I voted for the idea..